# Looking for road network of Uruguay?

Tags: data, uruguay

Does anyone know where I can get a reasonably accurate road network of Uruguay?

I have only managed to locate a very sparse one, and those roads are often a mile out of position. TAB or SHP file would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to get global road networks are Open Street Map.
You can download roads, as well as other layers, straight from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/uruguay.html) as a .shp file

[image]